# How to disable UIToolbar flexible space item clicks

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I have a UIToolBar with some button items on it separated by a flexible space item.

Depending on the state of the app, some buttons are enabled or disabled. And when this happens, when the disabled button is clicked, instead of doing nothing, it sends the "click" event to other button item.

I then understood that this is a default behavior for the toolbar (or the flexible space item?): when you touch an empty space on it, it forwards the event to the closest button. However this is not very good for usability in my application.

Setting enabled OFF to the flexible space item does not change anything at all, and removing UserInteraction from the whole toolbar will make all buttons untouchable.

Is there any way to prevent this "click event forwarding" and simply ignore the touches on empty spaces or disabled buttons ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for anyone who wants to know, i couldn't do anything to solve it, you'd better do a better work with your ui.